# Derived value not calculating as expected using combination of FK and Triggers (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, trigger, foreign-key

I'm having trouble with calculating a derived value using a combination of triggers and foreign key constraints.

There are 3 tables involved in this arrangement

```
responses
------------------------
id_responses
text
n_comments


responses_has_comments 
------------------------
id_responses
id_comments


comments
------------------------
id_comments
text
```

the link table - reviews_has_comments (rhc) exists because comments can be added to several other types of content.

A cascading foreign key constraint on **rhc** removes rows when a **comment** or **response** has been deleted. This is working as expected. I have written a trigger to increment/decrement **n_comments** on **responses** when a change occurs in **rhc**.

The incrementing trigger is working fine, but the decrementing trigger is not. Here are the triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `inc_n_comments_in_responses`
    AFTER INSERT ON `responses_has_comments` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN   
            UPDATE responses
            SET n_comments = n_comments + 1
            WHERE id_responses = NEW.id_responses;

        END;
 $$

 CREATE TRIGGER `dec_n_comments_in_responses`
    AFTER DELETE ON `responses_has_comments` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE responses
            SET n_comments = n_comments - 1
        WHERE id_responses = OLD.id_responses;
    END;
$$
```

Can anyone cast their eye over this and point me in the right direction? As I understand it, the BEFORE and AFTER commands happen before and after the CASCADE.

**UPDATE**

OK - this is a case of RTFM (although in this instance the manual sucks....)

MySQL documentation on this matter shows that Foreign Key constraints do NOT activate triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

So - let's look at the options:

1: I can increase the scope of the delete trigger thus:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `dec_n_comments`
    AFTER DELETE ON `comments` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SELECT rshc.id_responses INTO @id_responses 
        FROM responses_has_comments AS rshc WHERE id_comments = OLD.id_responses            
        IF @id_responses IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE responses
            SET n_comments = n_comments - 1
            WHERE id_responses = @id_responses;
        END IF;   
        -- rinse and repeat for all linked "commentable" table data...        
    END;
$$
```

My problem with this is that as the types of content to which comments can be added increases, so to will the size of this IF/ELSE (and it's bigger brother, the UPDATE trigger)

I could possibly remove the multiple IF/ELSE statements this points to 
if I write a PROCEDURE to return a placeholder table name and identifier to 
use in the subsequent UPDATE clause. This would require an additional field
on the comments table in order to get the relevant table type - but I'm 
personally suspicious of referencing table meta data in this way...

I could possibly replace the resource/link/comment paradigm with a one to many
relationship - suffixing each type of comment with it's parent resource: i.e response_comments

Finally - I could just sack this off and keep it in the application - which at the moment
is really looking like the most likely option.

Answer (score 3):

> reviews_has_comments (rhc) exists because comments can be added to several other types of content.

If I understand correctly, that is not a justification for `responses_has_comments` table - you can have several tables with 1-to-many relationships with the same `comments` table. The only reason for introducing `responses_has_comments` would be if the same comment can be attached to more than one response, as well as more than one comment being attached to each response, ie it is a many-to-many relationship - I don't think that is what you are trying to achieve.

This does not answer your main question but may sidestep the problem in your updated trigger. Your `comments` trigger then becomes:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `dec_n_comments`
    AFTER DELETE ON `comments` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE responses
        SET n_comments = n_comments - 1
        WHERE id_responses = @id_responses;
        -- rinse and repeat for all linked "commentable" table data...        
    END;
$$
```

Comment: Wouldn't the comments table then require a nullable foreign key index for each of the tables it was related to? How would you set up this relationship? Several tables "_has_comments" besides responses. I guess I could put an "abstract" name for the identifier on the comments table..

Comment: Yes, would add a nullable foreign key index for each of the tables it was related to if you want to stick with a single `comments` table. You can then also constrain the FKs so that no more than one of them can be non-null with a check constraint if you wish.

Comment: Hmmm - that just doesn't sit right with me,you're just pushing complexity into the application layer - and surely it's a normalisation no-no..

Comment: The application layer doesn't need to know how this is modelled - make it simple with a view for each kind of comment if necessary. If you don't like nullable FKs (and I'd say there is nothing wrong with them), bite the bullet and have separate comments tables for each.

Comment: Sure, it's not a criticism, more a preference. I would at this point rather push the complexity into the triggers than adopt this pattern. Thanks for taking the time to deal with the question.

Comment: FYI the issue of the triggers not firing is [a bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11472)

Comment: Yup, I know - and one that's been in there for a considerable amount of time. Starting to think I might give PG a whirl instead for the next app. I'm just going to have to write a big ole if/else into the trigger to deal with it - it's arguably a trivial piece of data and I don't want to overhaul the application/schema to accommodate it. Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I personally love Postgres for all sorts of reasons and it is fair to say that it is in some ways more mature than MySQL (which is not to denigrate MySQL). I highly recommend you do give it a whirl :)